# Unable to Call getAllSites API from Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

We are using yodlee's developer account to call APIs. We are able to get response from some Apis but we are not able hit `getAllSites` API. It is giving us error message as 
***"This API service is not permitted for the current endpoint."***

Below is my API URL :: /jsonsdk/SiteTraversal/getAllSites

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Yodlee's TestDrive tool to test this API.
As this API provides huge data in the response we recommend not to use this API in Yodlee's SandBox environment, though in case if you really want to test it you can call this API using either AdvanceRestClient or Postman extensions.

Comment: I tried calling this getAllSites API using Advance RestClient and Postman, but it is giving error with error code 415 system_error.

Comment: Please make sure you do not have any space in the URL and also you are passing the right parameters.

Comment: I want to call "getItemSummarisesForSite" from my application, for that i want 'CobSessionToken','UserSessionToken' and 'memSiteAccId' please tell me API's to get All these Id's

Comment: You need to call
1.cobLogin-> To get the CobSessionToken
2.login-> To get the userSessionToken
3.AddSiteAccount1-> To add an account, in the response you'll get siteAccountId(which is same as memSiteAccId) which you need to pass in getItemSummariesForSite API.

You can also follow the API flow for add account as mentioned here> http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account

Comment: I didn't find any Login API in API list please guide me to call login API for getting UserSessionToken

Comment: Is it necessary that user must be registered to get UserSessionToken?               if no then how to add new user and get UserSessionToken?                                    if yes, then how to register new User ?

Comment: Yes, user has to be registered. Here is the [API](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/register3) to register a new user, while use [this](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/login) API to login a registered user.

Comment: I get site Id by SearchSite API call ,Now I want to call "getItemSummariesForSite" API for that i want memSiteAccId ,now i'm getting siteAccountId by making "getAllSiteAccounts" API call. Is there any other API call where i can get SiteAccountId by providing cobsessiontoken,usersessiontoken and siteId

Comment: I didnt get how to call "AddSiteAccount1" API ,please tell me procedure